# Injecting javascript within innerHTML is not supposed to work so why it does here?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

According to this thread [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) **injecting some javascript in innerHTML** is not supposed to work.

So why it does work in that case :

```
<BR>
Below is the code injected with a div
</BR>
<div id="div_content">
</div>    

<script>
function HttpRequest(url){
var pageRequest = false //variable to hold ajax object
/*@cc_on
@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    try {
    pageRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch (e){
        try {
        pageRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch (e2){
        pageRequest = false
        }
    }
@end
@*/

if (!pageRequest && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

if (pageRequest){ //if pageRequest is not false
pageRequest.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously 
pageRequest.send(null)
embedpage(pageRequest)
}
}

function embedpage(request){
//if viewing page offline or the document was successfully retrieved online (status code=2000)
if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || request.status==200)
///document.write(request.responseText)
div_content.innerHTML = request.responseText;
}

HttpRequest("http://localhost/ajax/injecthtml/demo4/external.html") //include "external.html" onto current page
</script>
```

external.html

```
<img src="google.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" onclick="alert('Embedded Javascript within innerHTML works !!!')">
<br>
<img src="google.jpg" alt="" width="" height="" onclick="alert('Embedded Javascript within innerHTML works !!!')">
```

Comment: Are you sure about it? See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v610Lyv0/)

Comment: @MoshFeu yes I'm sure since I tested it and made a screenshot from the test. I use pure Javascript, not jquery and it works.

Comment: @MoshFeu maybe yours does not work because you use relative url, it must be absolute url at least in chrome for security reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javascript is not being executed when you load the page. You're just loading `<img>` tags that have `onclick` attributes, and when you click on them the code in the attributes is executed. That's just ordinary HTML.

What doesn't get executed when you assign to `.innerHTML` is `<script>` tags.